# Disabling single script within a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

By searching a bit, one could find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698059/disable-single-javascript-file-with-addon-or-extension) about stopping chrome from loading a javascript file.
But this doesn't work for a script which is not linked, for example:

```
<!-- Some html here -->
<script id="script">
//Some script here
</script>
```

The script here is coded inside the html page and not linked from an external .js file. As you can see, I'm looking for a way to disable that and only that `#script` before it gets loaded.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want to just disable this specific script, or every script, on the page?

Comment: This specific script of course.

Comment: Once the script is loaded, its in memory so even if you remove it, its still there. Only thing you can do is load them when you need it.

Comment: @AamirAfridi That's the reason of my question. I want to make chrome remove that part of code before it's executed.

Comment: If you don't want it to be executed, why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: ^ It's not my website.